# Why does an underscore as the last character in a character set cause GNU sed not to match text containing a hyphen?

Tags: regex, sed

I've run into very strange behavior I'm trying to understand in sed (GNU sed) 4.8 on Ubuntu.

This works:

```
$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\]/REPLACED/'
REPLACED
```

But when I add an underscore, escaped or not, to the character set, it fails:

```
$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\]/REPLACED/'
[some-text]

$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\]/REPLACED/'
[some-text]
```

Changing the order of the hyphen and underscore seems to work, whether or not either character is escaped:

```
$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\]/REPLACED/'
REPLACED

$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\]/REPLACED/'
REPLACED

$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\]/REPLACED/'
REPLACED

$ echo "[some-text]" | sed -E 's/\[([a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+)\]/REPLACED/'
REPLACED
```

Trying without the brackets, having an optional underscore prevents the match:

```
$ echo "thing by itself some-text" | sed -E 's/thing by itself ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/REPLACED/'
REPLACED-text

$ echo "some-text" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/REPLACED/'
REPLACED-text
```

But only if it's the last thing in the character set:

```
$ echo "some-text" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/REPLACED/'
REPLACED

$ echo "some-text" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/REPLACED/'
REPLACED
```

Is underscore at the end of a character set supposed to have special meaning, or is this a bug?

Comment: This is a regex rule, you need to put the dash at end of character class.

Comment: `echo '\' | sed 's/[\]/aha/'`

Comment: `echo 'TUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdef' | sed 's/[T-Wd-f\-_]\{1,\}/(hmmm...)/g'`

Comment: [Section 9.3.5 bullet point #7 here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html):
The <hyphen-minus> character shall be treated as itself if it occurs first (after an initial '^', if any) or last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.  ... (and much more explanation after that)

Comment: Thanks Giles and Steve, the problem is indeed that the hyphen needs to be the last character. I thought escaping it would cause regex to treat it literally, but evidently not.